# Difference between Steal/No-Steal and Force/No-Force policies in database recovery

Tags: recovery

It is said that **No-Steal policy** means that transaction's updated buffer block is not written to the disk before the transaction commits and **No-Force policy** has a similar definition.

What's the difference between them?

Answer (score 68):

Suppose a transaction T1 wants to read a data object X, but the working memory is full with all the other transactions' work. So T1 needs to clear some memory, which it does by kicking some other page in working memory to stable storage. This can be dangerous, because we can't be sure that what T1 is pushing to stable storage has been committed yet. This is known as stealing.

Forcing means that every time a transaction commits, all the affected pages will be pushed to stable storage. This is inefficient, because each page may be written by many transactions and will slow the system down.

Most crash recovery uses a steal/no-force approach, accepting the risks of writing possibly uncommitted data to memory to gain the speed of not forcing all commit effects to memory.

Comment: Nice explanation :D Help me remember those concepts :D "Stealing" really makes me difficult to understand until I see this post.

Comment: **Question:** Why is it dangerous that we can't be sure that what T1 is pushing to stable storage has been committed yet?

Comment: @SebastianNielsen because we haven't committed the working memory at that point yet. This can lead to a dirty write, if some other transaction reads that data.

Comment: Does `force` cause uncommitted data written into the stable storage too? I guess it's the case because `force` causes all the related pages to be pushed to the stable storage, some of these pages may contain uncommitted data from other transactions. Am I right?

Comment: @Searene you are right

Answer (score 0):

They may look similar, but they are not the same.

Look at this diagram:

[image: Steal & No-Steal and Force & No-Force]

Transaction's buffer blocks ...

- **Steal:** can be moved into the disk, as soon as it starts.
- **No-Steal:** cannot be moved into the disk, until it commits.
- **Force:** should be moved into the disk no later than when it commits.
- **No-Force:** can be moved into the disk, even after it commits.

### Key points:

- **Steal / Force** is used in Immediate Database Modification (IDM) method
- **Steal / No-Force** is widely used in most systems (It is used in IDM too).
- **No-Steal / Force** has the worst performance.
- **No-Steal / No-Force** is used in Deferred Database Modification (DDM) method.